# How to solve this limit containing $e$

Tags: calculus, limits

I've been trying to solve this for two hours now, searched for any techniques I could use and no luck, any help would be appreciated.

If $f(x) = e^{\tan x}$ , then what is

$$\lim \limits_{x \to \frac \pi4} \frac{f(x)-f(\frac \pi4)}{x-\frac \pi4}$$

Comment: Can you use L'hopital's rule? Do you know what a derivative is?

Answer (score 4):

This is a rate of variation of $f(x)$ starting from the value$\frac\pi4$, so the limit is $f'\bigl(\frac\pi4\bigr)$ by definition.

Answer (score 3):

The limit is equal to $f^{\prime}(\frac{\pi}{4})$, which can be computed using the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

Use L'Hopital's rule, you'll get :

$$\lim \limits_{x \to \frac \pi4} \frac{f(x)-f(\frac \pi4)}{x-\frac \pi4}=\lim \limits_{x \to \frac \pi4} f'(x)=f'\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

Since $$f(x)=e^{\tan x} \implies f'(x)=e^{\tan x} \cdot \sec^2 x$$

Therefore $f'\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)=e^{\tan \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)} \cdot \sec^2 \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=e^1 \cdot(\sqrt2)^2=2e$

Hence :

> $$\lim \limits_{x \to \frac \pi4} \frac{f(x)-f(\frac \pi4)}{x-\frac \pi4}=2e$$

Comment: Or rather, use the definition of the derivative.

Comment: I didn't, looking the level of OP, most probably (s)he doesn't know that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the definition of the derivative is taught before L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: It isn't, I am a highschool student and I know this, we are taught in Physics *how to take a derivative* rather than it's definition in beginning of 11th grade. Since Limits is taught before derivatives (in mathematics) and after *calculus in Physics*, we use L'Hospital's rule (remembering the standard results of derivative,) as a shortcut without knowing actual definition of derivative.

Comment: @khaled014z See this : [L'Hospital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way:

$$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{e^{\tan x}-e^{\tan\frac{\pi}{4}}}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}} = e^{\tan\frac{\pi}{4}}\cdot\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{e^{\tan x-\tan\frac{\pi}{4}}-1}{\tan x-\tan\frac{\pi}{4}}\cdot\frac{\tan x-\tan\frac{\pi}{4}}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}} = e\cdot\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}-\frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{4}}{\cos \frac{\pi}{4}}}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}} = e\cdot\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\sin (x-\frac{\pi}{4})}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos (x)\cdot\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})} = 2e$$
Using the standard $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$$ and
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$